# Plural of  "presence"

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns

What is the correct way to indicate multiple "presence"s in the sense of "I have a strong presence in this community"?

For example:

> I have multiple online presence[s?].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems strange to me to use *presence* in this sense.  [*Presence*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/presence) by its nature refers to the state of being present or proximal, and so you couldn't multiply be in this state.  You are present or you are not present.  So I would suggest

> I have a presence in multiple online communities.

is actually what you want.

Even if you are referring to many people, presence still refers to a state, and ought to be singular

> We have a demonstrable presence on English Language and Usage.

Answer (score 5):

The use of *presence* in the online sense is new enough that you're not likely to find it in many dictionaries, but I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be considered a countable noun--you're talking about multiple discrete accounts with different services, rather than an overall amount of "presence." *Presences* it is.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting a meaning of presence that is like "personality" or maybe "embodiment of a distinctive character" or suchlike? If that's so, then yes, I agree that it would be countable and therefore *presences*. But I haven't seen a definition like that, even though I understand the sense of it.

Comment: I was thinking more of the online presence indicator in things like IM applications, Facebook, Skype, etc.--if it's green you're there and available to chat, and so on. If you are on a service, you have *a presence* there. If you are on multiple services, you have *presences* on all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Pluralizing "presence" in this way is the target of debate into [schizophrenic-like cognition.](http://www.mikeybee.com/internet-schizophrenia/)

> My presence spans multiple usernames, each of which are registered at several online communities.

That is a more-literal communication strategy, but reveals the awkwardness of relating with different people in different forums using *different voice*.

If not multiple usernames,

> My online presence spans multiple web communities.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp Rule 2b explains it. In this sense *presence* is a regular noun/object/thing. So to make it a plural you would simply write *presences*.

For clarification, I'm currently writing a story where a person has a 'presence' similar to an aura. It's a noun - a physical thing. Many people would mean many presences.

'He could feel multiple presences in the room.'